# How to Create and Use New Database for Neo4j Unit Test?

Tags: python, django, neo4j, cypher

For my Django REST project, I need to perform unit test on my neo4j database to ensure the data outputted is in the correct format. However, I must perform these unit test on a testing database that is different than the actual database. Currently the settings.py is arranged in such a way that the views.py will access the default database. How can I have the Unit test access the test database instead without changing the settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use setting.py to identify my Neo4j database. I have functions which I call for Neo4j and they load or query the database. The database is a variable used throughout my python code so that it can be easily changed and propagated to all the downstream code.

Here are a couple of these functions:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from pandas import DataFrame

neo4jdriver=GraphDatabase.driver(Neo4Server, auth=(Neo4UserName,Neo4Pswd),database='neo4j')
neo4jsession = neo4jdriver.session(database='neo4j')

def CypherToPandas(Q, database):
    driver=GraphDatabase.driver(Neo4Server, auth=(Neo4UserName,Neo4Pswd),database=database )  #"neo4j"))  #AzureLib.Neo4Pswd))
    with driver.session(database=database) as cyphersession:
        rslt = cyphersession.run(Q)
        df = DataFrame(rslt.data())
        cyphersession.close()
        driver.close()
        return df

def CypherToText(Q, database):
    driver=GraphDatabase.driver(Neo4Server, auth=(Neo4UserName,Neo4Pswd),database=database )  #"neo4j"))  #AzureLib.Neo4Pswd))
    with driver.session(database=database) as cyphersession:
        rslt = cyphersession.run(Q)
        r = rslt.data()
        cyphersession.close()
        driver.close()
        return r
```